# java class object and Types

Tags: java, class, object

Given a class

```
public class A {
  public static int classVal;
}
```

During run-time, does the type `A` become a reference to a `class Object`?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  A a = new A(); 
  A.classVal = 100;
  A.classVal = 200;
}
```

if `A.classVal` is a reference to static Class variable, then is `A` a reference to an Object that represents the class?

does `a.getClass()` refer to the same object as `A`?

**To clarify**

if `A.classVal` is a reference, and `A` is nothing more than a name, does a class just become part of a lookup table that uses the class name as a key? I am trying to understand what happens to a class at run-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `A` isn't a reference at all. It's just the class name. `A` is not an expression in its own right - it doesn't have a value. It can only be part of another expression (like `A.classVal` or `new A()`).

Comment: but when you call `new A()`, the jvm must `know` how to look this up - 'name space = A', call = '()'...

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus: I suggest you look at the generated byte code - but none of that means that there is "A reference `A`". How the JVM handles all of this is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

> `static` refers to the enclosing type and not to the instances

No `A` does not become a reference to a class Object. Each static member will be created for the *type* itself and for all the instances of the class the same copy will be used during the execution if you try to access the static member with instance.

It's a way to access the static member in Java with the name of class here `A.staticMember`.

Answer (score 1):

No. `A` is a class name, but `A.class` equals `a.getClass()`.

Answer (score 1):

No, the "A" is just the class. It is not a reference. 
"a" is an reference object. So, in case you would like to check the class, just compare: a.getClass() vs A.class. They should be equal.